# Creating indexes from a theoretical decimal/int, splitting into before and after arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting, floating-point

I'm currently populating `before` and `after` arrays with indexes, based on a number provided. If the input going in is an int, there will be three indexes (left, middle and right). If it is a decimal, there will just be two (left, right). There will me a maximum of three indexes to sort into a maximum of two arrays (before and after). To understand, here is some expected input/output:

```
input: 1
output: before [] after [0, 1, 2]

input: 1.5
output: before [] after [1, 2]

input: -3.4
output: before [3, 4] after []

input: 0
output: before [1] after [0, 1]
```

Essentially, the input index gets floored and ceiling'd (or, in the case of a whole number, their next/previous integers are used along with the original input). If any of the resulting integers are below 0, they get put in the `before` array, but their index is made absolute, otherwise they go into the `after` array. If they do get put into the `before` array, then they are put in to reverse order, such that they remain sorted in numerical order.

I have the below working code. But I feel like I could do much better. How would the community go about optimising this?

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var ouput = document.getElementById('output');

function getOutput(input) {

  var left = Math.floor(input);
  var right = Math.ceil(input);
  var middle;

  var before = [];
  var after = [];

  if (right == left)
    left--,
    middle = left + 1,
    right = left + 2;

  if (left < 0)
    before.unshift(Math.abs(left));
  else
    after.push(left);

  if (middle < 0)
    before.unshift(Math.abs(middle));
  else if (typeof middle == 'number')
    after.push(middle);

  if (right < 0)
    before.unshift(Math.abs(right));
  else
    after.push(right);

  return {before: before, after: after};
  
}

function buttonPressed () {
  
  var i = parseFloat(input.value);
  var msg = 'not a number';
  
  if (!isNaN(i)) {
    
    var o = getOutput(i);
    
    msg = 'before [' + o.before.toString() + '] ahead [' + o.after.toString() + ']';
  
  }
  
  ouput.innerHTML = msg;
  
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<input id="button" type="button" value="get" onclick="javascript:buttonPressed();">
<br><br>
<div id="output" style="font-family: monospace;"></div>
```

My interest is in the `getOutput` method. The other stuff is for demonstration purposes.

**Update**

I have adjusted the expected output and the code from the original question, after being prompted to rethink from the comments.

Comment: The code and the description disagree on the result for -3.4.  The text says that `before` should be `[-3, -2]` but the code produces `[-4, -3]`.  Which is the intended result?

Comment: @Edward apologies, the intended result is [-4, -3]. Have corrected the Question.

Comment: And what is the task you are solving with these before/after?

Comment: @RomanSusi I'm essentially trying to resolve a situation whereby I can logically reference arrays with negative indexes. In a perfect world, arrays would be able to be addressable by the index `-n`, but doing this is not possible with JavaScript. Not if you want to use the Array prototype properly. Perhaps there is a better way to do this, I'm all ears. :-)

Comment: Just add array length to the negative index? (not sure about values like 0.5 though)

Comment: @RomanSusi that's certainly one improvement. And results will always be integers so `.5` is no issue when sorting. I was hoping for a little more improvement in the other areas of the business logic.

Comment: Asked, because that division into before/after looks like overcomplication for the place of use: The same information is already present a single array with the numbers you have.

Comment: @RomanSusi I agree, perhaps a single array like `[-1, 0, 1]` for input `0` would be better.

Comment: In other words, if you do not have very specific reason to use two arrays (you may have one), then this getOutput should be optimized together with the usage context.

Comment: @RomanSusi on rethinking, I would like to keep the `before` and `after` based on the fact that I will be needing to use positive indices for operations on the `before` array. Also, I have added a requirement that the `before` array be sorted numerically. The code now reflects this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question seems to have adequate complexity for the getOutput function. Some small hints may be given, like:

- do not use comma-expressions and decrement,
- initialize `middle` with `null` and check for it with `!==` instead of typeof,
- also, I do not like comparing undefined middle with 0.

The current code is more or less readable.

As for optimizations, one observation is that apart from [-1, 1] range, all other inputs always use the same alternative, making unnecessary to check left, right and middle individually. (eg, if right < 0, then so are middle and lift). How much optimization it really brings is hard to tell. If input numbers are almost always large, then making separate branch and constructing an array directly [left, middle, right] may make the code more efficient.

The near-zero case may need more conditions, of course (or just some kind of lookup for ready arrays - as the number of cases is small).

If you want a more compact code, maybe something like this can be done:

```
 tmparray = ((right == left) ? [left-1, left, left+1] : [left, left+1]);
```

And after that push/unshift in a loop for each tmparray element. Not sure this will be faster though, but at least may be more readable. (left may be renamed to "lower", and right calculated inline only in the condition).

Comment: This is a good, thorough review. Thankyou. I shall mark it later in the day when I've had time to implement some of your suggestions.

Comment: Just one point about your answer: ***"use of typeof where check for null may suffice"***. Do you mean, set the `middle = null` and then check? As `middle` may equal `0`, we cannot cast as boolean with the `!`. Also, is `typeof` considered much slower than checking `null`?

Comment: Thanks. Clarified the wording in the answer: use null and `!== null` check. Explicit is better than implicit. If you will use `tmparray`, then middle will not be needed at all.